# CSS3 Transitions NOT working on Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to get this semantic HTML Drop Down menu to work using CSS3 transitions. I have posted the HTML and the CSS for review. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I believe I did everything correctly. Not sure why its not working.

```
<nav id="mainNav" role="navigation" class="cf">
    <h2>Site navigation</h2>
    <ul class="topMenu">
      <li class="hover">
        <h3>Infant and Baby</h3>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Infant and Baby Shoes">Shoes</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Infant and Baby Hats">Hats</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Infant and Baby Clothing">Clothing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="millinery.html" title="Millinery Also Known as Hats">Millinery</a></li>
      <li class="hover">
        <h3>Shoes and Accessories</h3>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Shoes and Accessories - Mens Shoes">Mens Shoes</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Shoes and Accessories - Womens Shoes">Womens Shoes</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Shoes and Accessories - Bags">Bags</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="hover">
        <h3>Organic Skincare</h3>
        <ul class="subMenu">
          <li><a href="Organic_Skincare.html" title="Organic Skincare - Body">Body</a></li>
          <li><a href="shoes_and_accessories.html" title="Organic Skincare - Face">Face</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Garments.html" title="Garments">Garments</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

And Here is my CSS using the transition effects:

```
/*nav styles*/
#mainNav {
    padding-left: 3.9%;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
#mainNav li {
    margin-right: 3%;
    position: relative;
}
#mainNav a, #mainNav h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
/*dropdown menu styles*/
#mainNav ul.subMenu {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 2.8em;
    left: -8000em;
    max-height: 0;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    transition:max-height 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(76, 67, 65);
    background: rgba(76, 67, 65, .9);
}
#mainNav li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
    max-height: 20em;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#mainNav ul.subMenu li a:hover {
    background: rgb(123, 121, 143);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I tested it out in my browser and, while the design is very poor (text aligned weird, text out of place) the actual dropdown function appears to "work" (quote, un-quote).

Comment: the design is poor..http://jsfiddle.net/GaQFa/

Answer (score 0):

mriccelli75, just change a few things to fix the design, such as the removal of `text-align: center` and reduce the `padding` value on `.subMenu`. The *functionality* works, however, I would strongly advise changing the overall design (such as removing `list-style`, adding a grid-like system, or at least some way to make it "neater"). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GaQFa/1/ I'm not going to design the whole thing for you, but it gets you started as far as actual usability goes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did you change anything to get the functionality to work?

Comment: @mriccelli75 Not really. Before, you could access the drop down menu, but it would only flash a little bit before disappearing unless your mouse was in the right location. This was because your `h3` elements had a `text-align:center` making them hard to access. Also, your drop-down elements (sub-menus) had a large `padding-top`, separating them from the group, also making them hard to access. So I removed those two things. Try to tweak it and play around with it in order to make it more user-friendly.

Comment: Hello Again, If you visit: http://auldlangsynegoods.com/newHome you will see where I am trying to get that subMenu to pop up over the main homepage banner. I cannot for the life of me get it to work. The padding on top of the subMenu is set so that the top of the subMenu will align with the top of the banner image on the homepage. I CANNOT get the Z-INDEX to allow my subMenu to appear properly. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @mriccelli75 You should ask a different question (using the "Ask a Question" button) if you have another issue. Even if it's related. You can draw more attention to your problem that way, and also give other people another whack at it. That said, I'd love to help you, however, I checked out the link you gave me, and it appears there is no sub menu? I looked at the code, there isn't even code in the navigation menu for a sub menu?